# select a specific range on a excel sheet in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to developp a small tool in vba and as I am a beginner in this, I am having some trouble.

I would like to apply on specific cells of a column a treatment. This is my actual code :

```
For Each C In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("B").Cells
```

The problem with this code, is that is applying to all the cells of my column B, whereas I would like  to stop at a specific line (line which I am getting for another function (GetLine) that I have developped) :

```
Function GetLine(rw As Long) As Long
   GetNextEmptyCell = //my code
End Function
```

So I would like to know how  to specify in my foreach to stop at the number returned by my function.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Would `For Each C In ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & CStr(GetLine()))` work?

Comment: Use EXIT FOR to exit the FOR LOOP in case of MATCH CONDITION.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to loop from row 1 to the specified row:

```
For Each C In ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & GetLine).Cells
```